# Laravel Eloquent relations (need advice)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am having problem with Laravel Eloquent relations i understand how they work but i dont know how to "use" them properly, so i need some guidance/pointers.So here goes.

I have Exam table

*Schema* looks like (thanks to lukasgeiter)

**exams**

```
id
title
duration
```

**questions**

```
id
text
exam_id
```

**answers**

```
id
text
question_id
correct (boolean)
```

*Relations:*

**Exam Model**

```
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany('Question');
}
```

**Question Model**

```
public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('Answer');
}

 public function exam(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Exam');
}
```

**Answer Model**

```
 public function question(){
   return $this->belongsTo('Question');
}
```

And i understand this part but now i want users to be able to solve exam and store that data (i need to save an answer from user, for example user_id 1, exam_id 2, question_id 1, answer true). i have done it this way but i think its wrong (Yeah it does work but i dont think its the right way)

Schema looks like

**Users**

```
id
email
pass
...
```

**SolvedExams**

```
id
user_id
exam_id (havent put relation here not sure if needed)
solved (boolean) // if its completed right or wrong
```

**SolvedQuestions**

```
id
exam_id (havent put relation here not sure if needed)
answer(boolean)(then later i check this boolean with answers) //if the answer is right or wrong
```

Now with relations i have done same as i said before

**User Model**

```
public function SolvedExams() {

    return $this->hasMany('SolvedExams');
}
```

**SolvedExam model**

```
public function User() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

public function questions() {

    return $this->hasMany('solved');
}
```

**SolvedQuestions model**

```
public function exam() {
    return $this->belongsTo('SolvedExam');
}
```

Is this the right way or am i doing it wrong (and I am a begginer with relations)

Comment: What exactly is the `answer` boolean? shouldn't it be a foreign key to the answers table? Or is this just if the user got it right or wrong?

Comment: sorry will edit that, just if its right or wrong

Comment: Okay and can a user do the same exam multiple times?

Comment: 2 times... 2nd time gives out the questions he got wrong the first time if he got under 50% thats why i tought of using solved column on solved exams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pretty close...

I'd do it this way:

### Tables

#### exams

```
id, title, duration
```

#### questions

```
id, text, exam_id
```

#### answers

```
id, text, question_id, correct
```

#### users

```
id, email, password
```

#### tries

```
id, user_id, exam_id
```

#### answers_try (pivot table)

```
id, try_id, answer_id
```

### Relations

#### Exam

```
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany('Question');
}

public function tries(){
    return $this->hasMany('Try');
}
```

#### Question

```
public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('Answer');
}

public function exam(){
    return $this->hasMany('Exam');
}
```

#### Answer

```
public function question(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Question');
}

public function tries(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Try');
}
```

#### User

```
public function tries(){
    return $this->hasMany('Try');
}
```

#### Try

```
public function answers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Answer');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}


public function exam(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Exam');
}
```

### Usage

#### Get the users answer for a question

```
$answer = User::find(1)
              ->tries()->where('exam_id', 2)->first()
              ->answers()->where('question_id', 3)->first();
```

#### Creating a new exam

```
$exam = new Exam;
$exam->save();

$question = new Question;
$question->text = 'Foo?';
$exam->questions()->save($question);

$answer1 = new Answer;
$answer1->text = 'Foo!';
$answer1->correct = true;

$answer2 = new Answer;
$answer2->text = 'Bar!';
$answer2->correct = false;

$question->answers()->saveMany([$answer1, $answer2]);
```

#### Saving users answer

```
$exam = Exam::find(1);
$user = Auth::user();
$try = new Try;
$try->user()->associate($user)->save();
$exam->tries()->save($try);

$try->answers()->attach(2); // 2 is the answer id
```

Comment: it works had to replace $exam with $question, great now i just have to tie that to user, so that user for example 1 entered exam solved question foo? with answer Bar! and thats it :D ty

Comment: `$user = Auth::user();`
   `$try = new Tries;`
        
     `$exam = new SolvedExam;`
    `$exam->title = 'Test 1';`
    `$exam->save();`

   `$try->exam()->associate($exam)->save();`
   `$try->user()->associate($user)->save();`

Comment: I'm not sure, because in my proposal I had no `SolvedExam` model. And I don't think you need one...

Comment: Sorry about that i was just testing it with the model name `SolvedExam` it is `Exam` as you said.